# What course "xx is missing the Job/Configure permission"

Tags: jenkins

I have a problem with Jenkins configurations

On Jenkins > "BitbucketProjectName" > "RepositoryName" > Configure page
under tab General item Branch Sources > Bitbucker > Repository Name it says

```
Access Denied
xx is missing the Job/Configure permission
```

even thoug xx is configured as an Administrator on the Jenkins > Configure Global Security page (has enable security with Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy), this happens for several of my users

[image: Jenkins screen dump]

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Any fix for this @Jens that you have found?

Comment: No, I did not find a solution but it turned out that we didn't need to configure anything here yet